# POSTMAN : TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘Json’)

Tags: postman, typeerror

Body of output:
I am taking the token response from body and passing it to variable called "Token"

```
{
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.NS9nl4_3C9vsmogWntMXlg44E_pBhoL3oFryvl0wKsg"
    }
}
```

This is the test script:

```
{{
   var responseBody= pm.responseBody.json();
   pm.collectionVariables.get(responseBody.data.token);
   console.log(responseBody.data.token);`
}}
```

Problem : test result is failing showing Type Error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘Json’).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#parsing-response-body-data). Looks like you're using .responseBody where it should just be .response:

```
var responseBody = pm.response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let response = await fetch('website.com/api-request', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON({request:'test'}),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.token}
```

This is using node-fetch to post a request to website.com/api-request. This works in Javascript.

Comment: Can you please find the issue in the code i have written? i am new to coding and dont know JS. I tried your code, it shows SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules